# TS AudioContext: No audio with when BufferSourceNode is used along with HTMLAudioElement

Tags: typescript, audiocontext

I have two ways of playing audio.

1. Using BufferSource node
2. Using MediaElementSource node.

I have to have both ways in my app to handle some edge cases.

Whenever #2 is paused using audio.pause() there is no other audio coming out of #1 as well. When #2 is playing everything works fine and I am able to hear audio from both #1 and #2.

How can I decouple this ?

```
let audioContext = new AudioContext();
```

```
// #1 

let response = await fetch("./something.mp3")
arrayBuffer = await response.arrayBuffer()
audioBufferSourceNode = audioContext.createBufferSource();
audioBufferSourceNode.buffer = await audioContext.decodeAudioData(arrayBuffer);
audioBufferSourceNode.connect(audioContext.destination);
audioBufferSourceNode.start();
```

```
// #2
let audio = new Audio();
audio.src = "some src";
let mediaElementSource = audioContext.createMediaElementSource(audio);
if (audioContext.state === 'suspended') {
        audioContext.resume();
}
mediaElementSource.connect(audioContext.destination);
audio.play(); // Executing block #1. Works fine
audio.pause(); // Executing block #1. No audio from #1
audio.play(); // Executing block #1. works fine
```